# Textarea validation does not work Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

here is the code sample: 
HTML:

```
 <form id="information" name="information" action="#" method="post"> 
 <textarea name="text" rows="10" cols="10"> 
 </textarea> 
 <input type="submit" value="submit"/> 
 </form>
```

Javascript:

```
 window.onload=init;

 function init(){
 document.getElementById('information').onsubmit=validateForm;
 }

 function validateForm(){ 
 var text= document.information.text.value; 
 if(text==""){ 
 alert('text area cannot be empty');
 return false;
 } 
 }
```

it does not work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The textarea has a carriage return in it (and a space), so your condition is never true. So change it to:

```
<textarea name="text" rows="10" cols="10"></textarea>
```

However you may want to go further and stop the user entering an "empty" response (meaning nothing but white-space). Or you may just want to remove leading and trailing white-space. If so you can do this:

```
text = text.trim();
```

Now [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) I believe is relatively new (Firefox lists it as new in 3.5). A more backwards compatible version is:

```
text = text..replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');
```

and then testing if it's empty.

[Faster JavaScript Trim](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/faster-trim-javascript) has a good analysis on various white-space trimming alternatives. For instance the above can be done with one regex:

```
text = text..replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
```

but

> This commonly thought up approach is
>   easily the most frequently used in
>   JavaScript libraries today. It is
>   generally the fastest implementation
>   of the bunch only when working with
>   short strings which don't include
>   leading or trailing whitespace. This
>   minor advantage is due in part to the
>   initial-character discrimination
>   optimization it triggers. While this
>   is a relatively decent performer, it's
>   slower than the three methods above
>   when working with longer strings,
>   because the top-level alternation
>   prevents a number of optimizations
>   which could otherwise kick in.

Answer (score 5):

You've got a carriage return in your textarea - so its value is `\n` or `\r\n`
close your tag on the same line

Edit:
You could strip the beginning and end whitespace using this function

```
function trim( str ) {
    return str.replace( /^\s+|\s+$/g, '' );
}
```

Comment: exactly, he's right. If you don't specify anything you don't have the textarea's value property equal to "".

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
function validateForm(){
  var text = document.information.text.value;
  if(text == " \n "){
    alert("Error");
    return false;
  }
}
```