# Prohibiting specific HTML tags in textarea using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I use JavaScript to prevent the user from entering these HTML tags in a textarea?

```
<style></style>
<script></script>
<embeded></embeded>
<img src="" />
```

Comment: I think we would need more information on what you're actually doing. For instance, are people typing the markup in? Is it a TinyMCE/WYSIWYG editor? Do you want to prevent it in a POST, or on an event (onBlur for instance)?

Comment: Note though... you always want to do this on the server as well.  Never, ever trust a client-side validator if you're trying to 'forbid' something (like posting HTML to your DB).  In many cases, this just means doing it entirely on the server, and spitting back an error to the client... this way you can keep your business rules in a single place and not have to develop everything multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

There's a concern that sometimes is missed with respect to client side input validation with Javascript: It's possible for the validation process to be bypassed programatically, enabling the client to send tags (or in a more general sense, data) that your server-side script isn't expecting.  For example, someone could write a mechanized scraper that sends a GET or POST request directly to your server-side script.  Doing so bypasses the javascript input validation.  If your server-side script isn't also checking for valid input, it could get ugly.  In the worst case, a malicious user could take advantage of lax server-side scrubbing by possibly injecting data that would be harmful.

Javascript can, therefore, be used to 'encourage' well-behaved input, but it's not a substitute for rigorous server-side validation and scrubbing too.

Comment: ...In simpler words: if an attacker wants "bad" HTML tags in that textbox, JavaScript isn't going to stop them.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is using `onChange` event handler associated to your text area:

```
<textarea onchange="javascript:sanitizeHTML(this);>...</textarea>
```

In this way, your `sanitizeHTML` will be called whenever the text area content changes (focus out), and you can do your validation there by using regex.

If you prefer a more timely action to prevent user from entering the HTML you mention, you could define an `onkeyup` event handler as well, but you should be very careful about the implementation of your validating code as to its performance.

In your `sanitizeHTML`, you could use `str.replace` with some proper regex to remove unwanted content.

```
function sanitizeHTML(object) {
    object.value.replace("<embed>.*?</embed>", "");
    <etc for other tags>
}
```

Note: I have not checked the code and wrote it quite quickly...

Comment: ok, so when the tags are entered they are automatically removed?

Comment: see my edit for more detail. also changed handler name and argument now that it is clear how you would process the textarea content.

Answer (score 1):

### Javascript way:

### html

```
<textarea id="mytext" onChange="stripHTML(this.value);"></textarea>
```

### js

```
<script>
function stripHTML(oldString) {
  var result=(/<img.*|<script.*|<style.*|<embeded.*/ig).test(oldString);
  alert('Input is :'+!result);  
}
</script>
```

### jQuery way:

```
// remove onChange="stripHTML(this.value);" from html and do below
   <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mytext').live ('mouseleave change', function () { 
       var textVal= $(this).val();
       var result=(/<img.*|<script.*|<style.*|<embeded.*/ig).test(textVal);
        alert('input is:'+!result); 
    });
});
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xkeshav/f859Z/)

**[One useful link](http://www.ozoneasylum.com/5782)**

### [RUBULAR TEST](http://rubular.com/r/YJgKVeXojQ)

Comment: the question was for javascript, strip_tags is a php  function

Comment: Then this should not have been tagged PHP.

Comment: @lbu , see the tag there is `php` mentioned

Comment: @diEcho: What "see". He is asking for javascript solution. You are answering blindly.

Comment: @daric, i think u didn't see the tag

Answer (score 1):

This might take you to the right direction.[help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212893/textarea-validation-does-not-work-javascript) and [this](http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-86923.html)

```
str=(document.getElementById('exp')).value;
        if(str.match(/([\<])([^\>]{1,})*([\>])/i)==null)
         alert("No HTML Tag");
        else
         alert("Contains HTML Tag");
```

or

```
var htstring = '<p align="Left"><b>Hello</b> <I>World</I></p>'; 
var stripped = htstring.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,""); 

with (document) { 
write ('Original string:' + htstring + '<br>'); 
write ('Stripped string:<br><br>' + stripped); 
}
```

Comment: I don't know how helpful that particular question is to this one.

Comment: I don't see how this SO question could help the OP.

Comment: does not help at all, this question is about removing unwanted tags from the textarea, not removing spaces

Comment: You would be better off actually adding some code to your answer. Linking to another site is not a good practice on SO, since the linked page might one day disappear.

Comment: I would not see that as being the most relevant part of the forum post you link to - see Kor's response towards the end.

Answer (score 0):

I have written the following answer that is a generalization of this problem.
Just reduce the list of tags of the regexp to your own list.

[JavaScript - Detect HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631775/javascript-detect-html/16032045#16032045)